# specialization of variadic template function for std::tuple as return type

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, specialization

I'm implementing a template function which parses a string and returns a tuple of objects, like

```
template <typename... Objects>
std::tuple<Objects...> convert2data(const std::string_view& input) {
    return std::tuple<Objects...>{ internal::popNext<Objects>(input)... } ;
}

// usage
auto data = convert2data<int, double>("1, 0.01") ;
```

I specify the expected types as template arguments. Now I'd like to get the types "directly" from a named tuple type, perhaps more convenient for a user:

```
using MyData = std::tuple<int, double> ; // included from some header
auto data = convert2data<MyData>("1, 0.01") ;
std::cerr << std::get<int>(data) ;
// or better
MyData data2 = convert2data("1, 0.01") ;
```

I'm stuck in attempts to specify a specialization for this case, e.g. this code

```
template <typename... Objects, class std::tuple<Objects...>>
std::tuple<Objects...> convert2data(const std::string_view& input) {
    return convert2data<Objects...>(input) ;
}
```

does not get compiled. Is there a way to define such specialization for a template function where template type is used in the return value?

Comment: I don't see how `convert2data("1, 0.01")` could possibly work. You seem to expect the return type (which must be known at compile time) to be somehow magically derived from the contents of the string (known only at run time).

Comment: I naively thought that `MyData data(convert2data("1, 0.1") )` would give compiler the needed type information, since it knows the types required by constructor.

Comment: `std::tuple` has templated constructors taking more or less anything (see (3) and (4) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)). But even if it didn't - function template parameters are generally deduced from the function call arguments, but not from its return type (there are exceptions - off the top, a conversion operator may deduce from the type it's asked to convert to; and maybe when a function is cast or assigned to a function pointer, it's possible the deduction works off both the parameter types and return type of that pointer, I don't remember for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
Tuple convert2dataHelper(const std::string_view& input,
                         std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(
      internal::popNext<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>(input)...);
}

template <typename Tuple>
Tuple convert2data(const std::string_view& input) {
  return convert2dataHelper<Tuple>(
      input, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}
```

This permits `convert2data<std::tuple<int, double>>("1, 0.01");` syntax.

---

Another approach based on partial specialization, that allows both `convert2data<int, double>(...)` and `convert2data<std::tuple<int, double>>(...)` to be called and do the same thing.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Convert2dataHelper {
  static std::tuple<Ts...> Do(const std::string_view& input) {
    return std::make_tuple(internal::popNext<Ts>(input)...);
  }
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Convert2dataHelper<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
  static std::tuple<Ts...> Do(const std::string_view& input) {
    return Convert2dataHelper<Ts...>::Do(input);
  }
};

template <typename... Ts>
auto convert2data(const std::string_view& input) {
  return Convert2dataHelper<Ts...>::Do(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to almost work, though it does not compile as it can not resolve ambiguity when finding 2 overloads of `convert2data<std::tuple...>`, looks like `enable_if` needs to be applied in function template parameters for basic types and for tuple...

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted both flavors to work at the same time. I added another possible approach that could do that.

Comment: Solution with structures works nicely, thanks! I would be grateful for a short explanation why one needs to 'wrap' functions inside template structures... It also seems the key point there is 'auto' returned from convert2data, having std::tuple there does not work...

Comment: Classes can be partially specialized, but functions can't be. As to the return type - the whole point of the specialization is to do something different when `Ts...` is in fact a single type that's a `tuple<Us...>`. In that case, you want the return type to be `tuple<Us...>` and not `tuple<tuple<Us...>>` (which is what `tuple<Ts...>` would turn into).